# How to write to text file after creating it?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract cell A2 from Excel and its offset (0,1) and put it in a created text file.

How to proceed, since I haven't declared a variable for the created text file?

```
Sub CreateFileandWrite()
Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, "Hello"
Print #1, strContent
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **A2** and its offset:

```
Sub FileMaker()

    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\sample1.txt" For Output As #1
        Print #1, Range("A2").Value
        Print #1, Range("B2").Value
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create the txt file with the code you can also do it this way

```
Public Sub txtfile()

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream

    filePath = "C:\Users\Nytro\Desktop"

    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath & "\" & "NameOfFile" & ".txt")

    Set cell = Cells(2, 1)
    Set cell2 = cell.Offset(0, 1)

    fileStream.WriteLine cell 'or fileStream.WriteLine cell & cell2 if you want to write them on the same line
    fileStream.WriteLine cell2

End Sub
```